# why does the solution of difference equation behave periodically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, periodic-functions

Hi: I'm am a total difference equation beginner but I noticed the following difference equation behavior and was wondering if it has a name or where I can read more about it. Suppose I have the following difference equation setup so I have

$ x_{0} = $ some initial value and the specific difference equation is:

$ x_{1} = (-2 \times (1-p)) \times x_{0} $

And, then, in general

$x_{k+1} =  p \times ( -2 \times(1-p) )\times x_{k} $  $~~~for~~~ k = 1,\ldots (n-1) $

where $n$ is finite. In this manner. the  values of $x_{k}$ go from $k = 0$ to $k = n$ and the recursion stops there.

What I noticed about the recurrence relation above, is the following:  Suppose

1)  I choose a value of $n$ and then set $p$ such that $p^n = \frac{1}{2}$.

2) Given this values $p$ and value of  $n$ and the initial value $x_{0}$, I calculate the values of $x_{k}$ for $k = 1, \ldots, n$.

3) Finally, I sum all  of the $x_{k}$ from $k = 1$ to k = n$.

I notice that, if I do the three steps above,  then it is always the case that Step 3 indicates that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{i}  = -x_{0}$. It doesn't matter what value of $n$ is chosen in Step 1.

Obviously this means that the solution is periodic in some sense of the meaning of periodicity. But, like I said,  I'm a total beginner in difference equations. So, my questions are: Is this a well known difference equation as far as it having this property ? Does it fall under some class of difference equations. Is it discussed somewhere because I don't know the difference equations literature much at all. Thanks for any references, links etc because I don't know where to look.

Comment: One thing I should have mentioned in my question. I understand that the reason for the behavior is because of the formula for the sum of a geometric progression. but that's the algebraic reason. My question is if this is some kind of difference equation that falls under some class of periodic difference equation solutions. or maybe it's the discrete version of a differential equation that has periodic solutions ??????